# Цикл while, суть работы. Язык си

Tags: c, массивы, строки, циклы, while

```
int c[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int v[5] = {1,7,7,7,7};
int i = 0;
while (c[i]=v[i] && c[i]) 
{
    printf("%d", c[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Результат -  11111111. Разве остановка не должна была произойти на 5м индексе, при c[i]='\0'? Почему происходит присваивание 1?

Comment: Как по-вашему, что означает условие `c[i]=v[i] & c[i]`? С учетом того, что `&` — побитовое И, а `&&` — логическое?

Comment: @Harry Лучше спросить - "что означают вот эти две черточки? `=`".

Comment: @Igor Тут он ответ дает: *Почему в этом цикле не срабатывает присваивание c[i]=v[i]* — присваивание.

Comment: @gbg Почему? Исходя из приоритетов, сначала вычисляется побитовое И, потом — присваивание. Это все равно что `x = a + x`, грубо говоря...

Comment: Парни, спасибо. Заметил ошибку с поразрядными операциями. Изменил описание вопроса.

Comment: Какое это имеет отношение к данному примеру? Если присваивание имеет меньший приоритет, чем И (как логическое, так и побитовое)? Происходит вычисление операндов `v[i]`, `c[i]`? затем вычисление `v[i] && c[i]`, затем присваивание `c[i]`. Где здесь место для UB? Это, еще раз повторюсь, такая же операция, как и `x = a + x` — где здесь UB?

Comment: @gbg По-моему, во всех случаях четкое следование приоритетам дает именно тот результат, который и получал ТС. Но раз вы утверждаете, что это не так — опишите, пожалуйста, последовательность действий, которая приводила к тем результатам, что писал ТС и которые я пояснил простым следованием приоритетам. Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что wbrk `while(x = x & y) { y++; }` является UB? а цикл `while(x &= y) { y++; }`?

Comment: @gbg Да как ни вычисляй `&`, оно единственное... Какой уж тут порядок вычисления... По приоритетам — сначала `&`, затем присваивание, затем — проверка значения выражения присваивания для принятия решения о выполнении итерации цикла...

Comment: @gbg, какие именно value computation и side effect являются неупорядоченными в выражении `c[i]=v[i] & c[i]` над одним и тем же scalar object?

Comment: Признаю свою неправоту в данном случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше выражение

```
c[i]=v[i] & c[i]
```

исходя из приоритетов трактуется как "вычислить `v[i] & c[i]` и присвоить полученное значение `c[i]`, если не 0 — выполнить тело цикла.

> Разве `& v[i]` не должен останавливать при `v[i] = '\0'`

Ну, да, конечно, должно остановить... Но где вы видите нулевой элемент в массиве `v`? Вы просто выходите за границы, получаете UB... Ну, и где-то — где в памяти сталкиваетесь с нулем, цикл прекращается.

**Update**

Исправление вопроса сути не поменяло. Массив у вас из 5 элементов, все ненулевые. Никакого "пятого индекса" просто нет — это уже за границей массива. Тем более нет никакой гарантии, что там находится нулевое значение...

Это справедливо только для объявлений со строковыми литералами, типа

```
char s[6] = "Hello";
```

Но и тут количество элементов должно быть либо не задано вовсе, либо задано в достаточном для нулевого символа количестве.